# Can't catch MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN of GridView

Tags: android, events, gridview

I have the following OnTouchListener

```
    gridview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                start_x = event.getX();
                start_y = event.getY();
                Log.d(TAG,start_x + " " + start_y);

            }
```

But the body of the 'if' statement is never executed. However, for other events, like ACTION_MOVE, the body of the corresponding 'if' statement does get executed.  Anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried changing the return value to true or false and see if it gets through?

Comment: @MarciCăşvan Yes, that's what I tried first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that the DOWN event is being consumed by another view.
Try overloading "onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)" in your activity, and see if you are able to catch the event.

Comment: You were right because I found onclick handler of items were cause of the problem. I resolved the issue by combining the same kind of events into single one. And that's the reason I accept your answer.