# How to get (x,y) coordinate of touched point in gridview parent at onClick event?

Tags: android, events, gridview

Since I [can't intercept action_down event for gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684568/cant-catch-motionevent-action-down-of-gridview), I would like to get (x,y) coordinate of touched point in gridview when one of its items is clicked. Is this possible?

Comment: you want to get the current x,y or the x,y for the gridview item?

Comment: Since I am in onclick event of gridview item, I have all the information of the item. I need to figure out x,y of gridview on that event.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this,

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
           int[] values = new int[2]; 
           view.getLocationOnScreen(values);
        }
```

Comment: I don't think it gives touched point but it is actual location of the item.